# Has anyone yet been able to prove relativity wrong?

Tags: relativity

I was in a physics group, then a student (or a professor, I don't know) posted this-

> Mohammad Shafiq Khan > Physics > The space-time concept including the formula $E=mc^2$ are proved baseless in the published paper "Experimental & Theoretical Evidences of Fallacy of Space-time Concept and Actual State of Existence of the Physical Universe" available at http://www.indjst.org/index.php/indjst/issue/view/2885 on the same premises on which Einstein had derived it.

Was Einstein wrong about relativity?

Comment: Fortunately, there are Wikipedia articles on tests of [general relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_general_relativity) and [special relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_special_relativity).

Comment: Direct link to the PDF file : http://www.indjst.org/index.php/indjst/article/viewFile/30369/26297

Comment: The author spends a good portion of the article calling Einstein's paper "trickery" while referencing his (Khan's) own papers as supporting evidence. Also, the paper seems o have been translated, which may cause the author's arguments to be unclear.

Comment: I note that if I Google for *Mohammad Shafiq Khan* at the top of the list is [this article](https://plus.google.com/117663015413546257905/posts/9E4ekrJADj1).

Comment: What do you think guys?I don't have any pdf complaint browser.But does the article make any sense?Can it be considered true what he wrote?

Comment: Also, he (Khan) says that "gravitation is an electromagnetic force", and the only references he gives (besides historical background) in the article itself are his own papers. Although he does include others in the proper 'References' section. Then again, he also thanks God for his support. Having now read a lot of this paper, I'm not sure if anything in the paper (besides some of the historical background) is a logical conclusion, or is accurate.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't *download* the PDF and view it in any number of standard PDF viewers, rather than a "pdf compliant browser"?

Comment: It failed.

Gonna try to download tomorrow in my PC.Thanks for the responses. :-) 

Sorry,If I did any grammatical mistake.I am bad in English.

Comment: You might be interested in this article: http://www.universetoday.com/108044/why-einstein-will-never-be-wrong/ .

Comment: I read that one in the past.That's why I asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Einstein's relativity hasn't been proved wrong by anyone up to now. Anyone who did would get a Nobel Prize.

Comment: You know this should be a comment.

Comment: @jinawee No, comments for questions are meant to clarify and help modify the question, not to answer it.